# HTTP basic authentication via URL doesn't work with Firefox?

Tags: http, firefox, authentication

Normally you can login to sites that require HTTP basic authentication by passing the username and password in the URL, e.g.:

```
http://myusername:myuserpassword@mydomain.com/mypath
```

On my Linux machine, I could access this website without problems with my Konqueror browser as well as with my Opera browser. But with Firefox it doesn't work? It always displays the "Authentication Required" dialog window?

Any ideas why it would work with the other browsers but not with Firefox?

Peter

Answer (score 3):

I got it now, the problem was that FF makes a distinction between

```
http://myusername:myuserpassword@mydomain.com/mypath
```

and

```
http://myusername:myuserpassword@mydomain.com/mypath/
```

Notice the "/" at the end of the URL. With the first URL login doesn't work, with the second URL it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of firefox are you using?

I just tried it and I get `You are about to log in to the site "example.com" with the username "myusername".`

If I click on 'ok', I log on perfectly... This is using Firefox 3.6.3 on Ubuntu 10.04

It does display the "Authentication Required" window if the password is wrong though, which is normal...

Comment: I have been using Firefox 2 and 3. With both I get the "Authentication Required" window. I am sure that I use the correct username/password combination as it perfectly works for my other browsers.